# how to disable apple wallet app when my app on foreground

Tags: nfc, applepay, suspend, wallet

I have iOS app, which have to work with NFC tag, the main issue is when I put my phone near NFC apple wallet app triggered over my app, so I need to find solution how to disable sisytem feature when my app on foreground

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

we can contact Apple to provide special entitlement for you app to prevent it while app is in foreground. More information: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617078-requestautomaticpasspresentation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.